# Viewing Ractive events in browser console

Tags: ractivejs

I've been reading the RactiveJS docs on event management at https://ractive.js.org/get-started/tutorials/events/, and had a question around rendering of events:

> Instead, the on- directive will bind a shared callback directly to the element using addEventListener when it is rendered.

Is it possible to see what the rendered event would look like? I know it won't appear within console, but it would be nice to see if there is a way of viewing an example of how a rendered event would appear.

Answer (score 0):

What that portion of the tutorials meant to say is that the `on-*` directive doesn't render inline JS nor render on the DOM at all. It's a directive that simply signals Ractive what to do. Even if the template looks like this:

```
<button on-click="@global.alert( 'Activating!' )">Activate!</button>
```

What ends up in the DOM is a button with an event handler.

```
<button>Activate!</button>
```

Under the hood, the `on-*` is processed from the parsed template and is converted to something roughly similar to the following:

```
buttonReference.addEventListener('click', function(){
  theGlobalDependingOnTheEnv.alert( 'Activating!' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph - this is perfect! It's a shame that we can't see the rendered result in a browser, but at least this better explains the conversion process.

Comment: @AlexLibby There's no point rendering `on-*` since it means nothing to the browser. You can inspect event listeners on the element using the Event Listeners on the Elements panel of the  Dev tools. Also, `event` is available to the expression. You can pass it as args to a proxy event or method call and you'll get the original event object.